# Why does the Grinder console only show 200 "Successful Tests"

Tags: performance-testing, grinder

Using the Grinder 3.11 on Windows I am trying to simulate 300 simultaneous users performing a logon, some actions and then logoff scenario by launching 300 threads by means of 2 agents on 2 different PCs each agent launching 150 threads. So each agent has a grinder.properties with these values:

```
grinder.processes=1
grinder.threads=150
grinder.runs=1
```

As the test is launched I notice on the console Results tab, in the column "**Successful Tests**" that Grinder ramps quickly up to 200, these 200 "users" complete the test scenario. Finally the remaining 100 are launched, they too complete the scenario. But this is not what I wanted or expected : I wish to have 300 users perform the test simultaneously not 200 then 100.

Why does Grinder run 200 followed by 100 users instead of 300 at once?
How do I run 300 users at once?

Answer (score 0):

No of simulated users are below :-

number of worker threads x number of worker processes x number test machines

In your case it seems only 150 threads will be created , however I doubt that all of them gets spawned at once and there is limitation to it . Try sending the same from more than one machine and u will see desired load .. try virtual machines as well